# Windows Easy Transfer - multiple attemps

Tags: windows-easy-transfer

How does Windows Easy Transfer transfer behave if you try it several times?

1) If you try to transfer the same items twice?

2) If you try to deselect items?

The reason for the questions, is that it is often interrupted, and also it is difficult to know exactly what to select.

This is XP - W7 (32bit)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct version? See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run Easy Transfer and get a sucessful file creation and then restore that to the new system.  You should not be able to select the same item twice